# WKWebView only allow the click event within DOM body [Objective-C]

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I am using iOS WKWebView to display a web page. The challenge I need to resolve is:

- The dynamic content of the page is changing, so sometimes the DOM body's height of the displayed HTML is shorter than the container WKWebView's height.
- how can I only allow the click event within the DOM body area, and disable any touch event outside the DOM body area when user touch the webview? Since the touch event on any area of the webview will trigger textFieldDidEndEditing of another textField outside the webview. I don't want this happens.

Thanks

Comment: Just a suggestion - you could enable and disable the whole WKWebView. This sometimes help to prevent click events although here I think you want something more complex.

Comment: @skaak, thanks for the suggestion first. If I disable the whole WKWebView, then it will also prevent the clicks to the elements that I want to click. So ya, I need something more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Create your main VC something like this.

```
// ViewController.m

#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

#import "PassthroughView.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () < WKNavigationDelegate >

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField     * textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKWebView       * webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet PassthroughView * overlay;
@property (nonatomic,strong)         NSNumber        * width;
@property (nonatomic,strong)         NSNumber        * height;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // Load some HTML
    NSURL * url = [NSBundle.mainBundle URLForResource:@"t"
                        withExtension:@"html"];
    
    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    [self.webView loadFileURL:url
      allowingReadAccessToURL:url];
}

// Navigation delegate
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation
{
    // Get width and height
    [webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.getElementById('inner').offsetWidth"
          completionHandler: ^ ( id result, NSError * error) {
        if ( error )
        {
            NSLog(@"Error getting width");
        }
        else
        {
            self.width = result;

            if ( self.height )
            {
                self.configurePassthrough;
            }
        }
    }];
    [webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.getElementById('inner').offsetHeight"
          completionHandler: ^ ( id result, NSError * error) {
        if ( error )
        {
            NSLog(@"Error getting height");
        }
        else
        {
            self.height = result;
            
            if ( self.width )
            {
                self.configurePassthrough;
            }
        }
    }];
}

// Configure the passthrough
- (void) configurePassthrough
{
    // Navigation done, prepare passthrough window
    self.overlay.passthrough = YES;
    self.overlay.hitRect     = CGRectMake ( 0, 0, self.width.doubleValue, self.height.doubleValue );
}

@end
```

This makes use of a passthrough view which is positioned so that it exactly covers the webview. Then you can use that to perform a hit test, as below. The size of the inner element is obtained using javascript and you have to wait for both width and height to be available before you can configure the passthrough, otherwise it is pretty straightforward.

Here is the passthrough. It overloads the hittest as shown below.

```
// PassthroughView.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PassthroughView : UIView

@property (nonatomic)      BOOL     passthrough;            // Pass through
@property (nonatomic)      CGRect   hitRect;                // Rectangle which is considered a hit

@end
```

and

```
// PassthroughView.m

#import "PassthroughView.h"

@implementation PassthroughView

- ( UIView * ) hitTest:( CGPoint   ) point
         withEvent:( UIEvent * ) event
{
    if ( CGRectContainsPoint ( self.bounds, point ) )
    {
        if ( self.passthrough && CGRectContainsPoint( self.hitRect, point ) )
        {
            return nil;
        }
        else
        {
            return self;
        }
    }

    return [super hitTest:point
            withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Since the `body` element is stretched to be the whole size of the `WKWebView` I used an inner view, in lovely cyan, to obtain the size of the hit test rectangle. Here is the HTML.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Long format data</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('click', printMousePos, true);
            function printMousePos(e){
                
                cursorX = e.pageX;
                cursorY= e.pageY;
                document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "x: " + cursorX +" y: " + cursorY;
            }
        </script>
        <div id="inner" style='background: cyan;'>
            <h1 id="test">x: y:</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```